# How do i continue from here in Expo React Native?

Tags: reactjs, native, expo

When i get to here i try to type but it only changes the slug and when i hit enter it says the last line ie. Required> etc

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\calculator>expo init mycal
? Choose a template: expo-template-blank
? Please enter a few initial configuration values.
 Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/ 
» 50% completed
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "<The name of your app visible on the home screen>",
    "slug": "mycal"
  }
}
```

> Required: The name of your app visible on the home screen

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tab-cycle through the input fields